# Numerical Issues with SoS solver

Tags: drake

I am running into numerical issues with the SoS solver when trying to verify the RoA of a system. I've tried both mosek and CSDP. The solver returns success even though the SoS constraint is violated.

The Lyapunov function is very small: V(x) = x.T P x where

```
P = [[ 6.88693913e-05  8.81733881e-09 -1.12596351e-06]
    [ 8.81733881e-09  6.89157664e-05  7.68071960e-05]
    [-1.12596351e-06  7.68071960e-05  5.00915262e-02]]
```

I've tried scaling P by 1e5, but this did not solve the problem.

Similarly, the lambda found by the solver has very small coefficients (the largest is ~1e-10).

When I manually check the SoS expression (V_dot + l * ( V - rho ) - eps * x.dot(x)) at a point inside of the sublevel set (x_sample = [-1000     0  2000]), I get a negative value:  -9278694612.

Here is the full output when evaluating the SoS expression at x_sample:

```
x_sample: 
[-1000     0  2000]
V(x_sample): 
200375.96901588634
rho:
300000.0
V - rho: 
-99624.03098411366
l(x_sample):
93125.29963587047
l(x_sample)*(V - rho): 
-9277517736.328829
-V_dot_x: 
-1176876.6274507358
-eps * x.T * x:
-0.5
-V_dot_x + l * (V- rho) - eps ( x.T * x)
-9278694612.95678
```

The expression is clearly not SoS, because it outputs a negative value. I believe this means that the problem is with the solver.

I am going to try scaling the variables of the problem to make P larger. Please let me know if you have any more suggestions.

Thank you.

P.S. The SoS optimization code is here:

```
def is_verified(rho):
    prog = MathematicalProgram()
    x = prog.NewIndeterminates(3, "x")
    V = x.dot(P_lyap).dot(x)
    V_dot = 2 * x.dot(P_lyap).dot(nonlinear_system(x))
    l_deg = 4
    assert l_deg % 2 == 0
    l = prog.NewSosPolynomial(Variables(x), l_deg)[0].ToExpression()
    eps = 1e-7
    prog.AddSosConstraint(-V_dot + l * ( V - rho ) - eps * x.dot(x))
    solver = MosekSolver()
    result = solver.Solve(prog)
    x_sample = np.array([-1000, 0, 2000])
    thisdict = {
        x[0]: x_sample[0],
        x[1]: x_sample[1],
        x[2]: x_sample[2]
    }
    l_result = result.GetSolution(l)
    l_sample =  l_result.Evaluate(thisdict)
    V_x_sample = x_sample.dot(P_lyap).dot(x_sample)
    V_dot_sample = 2 * x_sample.dot(P_lyap).dot(nonlinear_system(x_sample))
    print("x_sample: ")
    print(x_sample)
    print("V_x_sample: ")
    print(V_x_sample)
    print("rho")
    print(rho)
    print("V - rho: ") 
    print(V_x_sample - rho)
    print("l:")
    print(l_sample)
    print("l*(V - rho): ")
    print(l_sample*( V_x_sample - rho))
    print("-V_dot_x: ")
    print(-V_dot_sample)
    print("- eps * x.T * x")
    print(- eps * x_sample.dot(x_sample))
    print("-V_dot_x + l * (V- rho) - eps ( x.T * x)")
    print(-V_dot_sample + l_sample*( V_x_sample - rho) - eps * x_sample.dot(x_sample))
    return result.is_success()
```

Answer (score 0):

We've definitely seen the convex solvers return with false confidence when they have numerical issues.  There is some discussion on this topic, and some recommendations for interpreting the verbose solver output [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12876).  Your Lyapunov candidate is definitely in that danger zone.

A more general way of improving the numerics is by changing the coordinate system of the state space. A principled way to do that is to find the coordinates that makes `P` and the hessian of `Vdot` simultaneously diagonal and as close as possible to the identity.

You can see how we do it in the RegionOfAttraction code in Drake [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/f530be192c4ef4e5326c74536aef9f6fea310b5e/systems/analysis/region_of_attraction.cc#L53-L63) with the balancing implementation [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/drake/blob/c185d5dd5321ce59fb6c298e1f5e412f55750d6b/math/quadratic_form.cc#L74). Let us know if that helps?